# multiple or, like operator in mysql using cake php

Tags: cakephp

```
SELECT * FROM sf_jobs WHERE title LIKE '%abc%' or description like '%abc%' or fixed_price like '%abc%'
```

I have using this but it not worked.

```
$search = "abc";
$query =  $this->Job->find('all', array ("OR" => array ("title LIKE" => "%$search%","description like" => "%$search%","fixed_price LIKE"=>"%$search%")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->Job->find('all', array ("conditions"=>array("OR" => array ("model.title LIKE" => "%".$search."%","model.description like" => "%".$search."%","model.fixed_price LIKE"=>"%".$search."%"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->Job->find('all', array ("conditions"=>array("OR" => array ("title LIKE" => "%".$search."%","description like" => "%".$search."%","fixed_price LIKE"=>"%".$search."%"))));
```

Comment: open to sql injection... Use "?" placeholders

Comment: Is it?  I've found that making queries 'model.field LIKE' => '%' . $string . '%', $string gets escaped, at least in 2.3.  I'm just legitimately wondering if it's vulnerable or not, since it escapes.